# ldap_modify_s causes an access violation where ldap_add_s works with the same code

Tags: ldap

I saw another example of this but it didn't fix my problem.  So the code sample below works as is.  But, if I change the ldap_add_s command to ldap_modify_s command and change the LDAP_MOD_ADD to LDAP_MOD_REPLACE  (with Martin rather than Marshall Fielding - the rest should just do nothing), I get the access violation:

Unhandled exception at 0x74c923b6 in LDAPAPP.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000002.

This make no sense to me since I haven't changed anything to cause an access violation, it must be coming from the ldap call somehow.  HELP!

```
char * myDn = "acctName=judy,ou=players,o=myCompany";
char *classValues2[] = { "ejCharacter", NULL};
char *cidValues[] = { "12", NULL };
char *firstValues[] = { "Marshall", NULL };
char *lastValues[] = { "Fielding", NULL };
char *genValues[] = { "CS_Male2", NULL };
char *ouValues[] = { "players", NULL };

objClass2.mod_op =  LDAP_MOD_ADD;
objClass2.mod_type = "objectClass";
objClass2.mod_values = classValues2;

charID.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD;
charID.mod_type = "ejCharID";
charID.mod_values = cidValues;

first.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD;
first.mod_type = "ejCharNameFirst";
first.mod_values = firstValues;

last.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD;
last.mod_type = "ejCharNameLast";
last.mod_values = lastValues;

gen.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD;
gen.mod_type = "ejCharGenData";
gen.mod_values = genValues;

ou.mod_op = LDAP_MOD_ADD;
ou.mod_type = "ou";
ou.mod_values = ouValues;

NewChar[0] = &objClass2;
NewChar[1] = &charID;
NewChar[2] = &first;
NewChar[3] = &last;
NewChar[4] = &ou;
NewChar[5] = &gen;

printf("myDN %s\n", myDn);
printf("OKAY TRYING THE ADD");

retVal = ldap_add_s(ldap_session, myDn, NewChar);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366943%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The array of LDAPMod(s) must be NULL terminated.

There's a good chance you may resolved the error by increasing your array size by one and adding the following:

```
NewChar[6] = NULL;
```